# Align layout to parent bottom not working - After setting layout height programatically

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to place the fragment at the bottom of the screen. By setting the property `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, the fragment is placed as my requirements.

Now I'm trying to specify the height of the fragment programatically. The height is being set properly. But the fragment is not placed at the bottom of the parent.

**Here is me code:**

**fragment_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="#4e534d"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.gokul.myprogram.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, screenHeight/2);  // Commented
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;       // Commented
        rootView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);      // Commented
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot Without Commenting:**

[image: Without Commenting]

**Screenshot With Commenting: (See `// Commented`)**

[image: With Commenting]

Comment: can you post your screenshot?

Comment: @Anjali: Screenshot Attached.

Comment: which one you need, first or second?

Comment: I am not clear, when you comment d code the layout will come at the bottom, that is working. Now I think the height is not excatly half and need to be resoved. Is that correct?

Comment: @droidkid: I need to get the second one without commenting the lines. That is I've hard coded as "200dp" in XML. But I want to find the height dynamically and make the fragment size accordingly. Currently I'm able to get the height and resize the fragment. But the fragment is not aligned to the bottom of the screen/parent.

Comment: adding gravity to view wont work. Instead add gravity to activity framelayout/fragment where you are attaching this fragment